# CSS Modules vs. normal CSS to change background of page in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

Edit: The accepted answer helped me arrive at the problem. It is correct so I accepted it. But I was importing my module which included the `body` tag and not using it.

`import styles from "./App.module.css"; //Includes a body tag`

`styles` isn't used anywhere in the code, so I don't think WebPack was including it. If I did *anything* with that module, the body tag was included and it worked. `<div className={styles.anything}>` allowed the `body` CSS to be included.

This could be due to Typescript as the answerer said in a comment.

---

I used `create-react-app` to make an app. I'm using CSS Modules in my components. I'm trying to figure out how to use CSS Modules to make the overall background of the page a different color.

I want to apply `background-color: #121212;` to the entire background.

I'm trying to figure out how to apply that style, and right now it seems it would need to be applied to the `body` tag.

Any styles applied to `App.tsx` only affect the container which that component takes up (The background is colored only to the bottom of the `App` component and white below it)

Right now `index.css` contains

```
body {
  ...
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

This works fine. I'd like to use modules though, and I don't know how I can import that style to work.

Where would I import a style on the `index.tsx` file created by `create-react-app` with Webpack.

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up one of your `.module.css` file, and paste this:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

CSS modules, just like CSS files, are imported and applied globally by `Webpack`.

If you want to create another `.module.css` just for the `body` tag, then you can create a new module, for example, `MyModule.module.css` and paste the above code. Then, import this new module to one of your `tsx` file.

You don't need to do anything with it, just import like this:

```
import myStyles from "./MyModule.module.css";
```

Comment: Wow... thanks. I tried this, but it wasn't being imported because it wasn't being used I'm guessing. So if I never use `myStyles` it appears Webpack doesn't import it. But if I use `myStyles.Anything` in my code, it then works and imports `body`.

Comment: I tried this before posting my answer, and it worked. However, I imported `MyModule.module.css` from a `.js` file. Maybe it is related with `TypeScript`. @Diesel

Comment: This does not work for next.js, you have to use `<style global>` to make it work.